# Why am I getting ' Incompatible value type Object for Map' error?

Tags: apex, map

I need to populate values in `map<id, list<object_B__c>>()`.  I am getting an error when I attempt to do this.  I was able to get code to compile but the problem is the way it's compiled, each iteration of my for loop creates a new list instead of a new list value.  Intuitively, what makes sense doesn't seem to compile and I'm not sure why.  Any insight as to why my code won't compile as well an a workaround is greatly appreciated.

This code compiles but creates a new list with each iteration of the loop:

```
Map<string, object_A__c> myAMap = new map<string, object_A__c>()
for(object_A__c objA: [SELECT  field_A__c, field_B__c from object_A__c]){
      myAMap.put(objA.field_A__c, objA); 

}
system.debug('***** myAMap  ' + myAMap);

map<id,list<object_B__c>> results = new map<id,list<object_B__c>>();

for(object_B__c objB: [SELECT id, field_A__c, field_B__c from object_B__c]){
  if(myAMap.containsKey(objB.field_A__c)){
    results.put(id, new list<object_B__c> {objB} );
  }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do but can't compile:

The error:  Incompatible value type Object for `Map<id,list<object_B__c>>`

```
   Map<string, object_A__c> myAMap = new map<string, object_A__c>()
   for(object_A__c objA: [SELECT  field_A__c, field_B__c from object_A__c]){
      myAMap.put(objA.field_A__c, objA); 
   }
   system.debug('***** myAMap  ' + myAMap);

   list<object_B__c> myList = new list<object_B__c>();
   map<id,list<object_B__c>> results = new map<id,list<object_B__c>>();

   for(object_B__c objB: [SELECT id, field_A__c, field_B__c from object_B__c]){
     if(myAMap.containsKey(objB.field_A__c)){
       results.put(id, myList.add(objB) ); // This line has the error.
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [add method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_add) on `List` returns `void`, which is why you are getting an error on this line:

```
results.put(id, myList.add(objB) );
```

What is happening is `myList.add(objB)` is being executed first and nothing is returned so what actually gets put into your map is `void`, shown below. Hence the  "Incompatible value" error.

```
results.put(id, void);
```

You need to add to the `List` before putting it into the `Map`. The example below gets the `List` from the `Map`, makes sure the `List` is instantiated and then puts it back into the `Map`

```
myList = results.get(key);
if (myList == null) {
    myList = new List<object_B__c>();
}
myList.add(objB); 
results.put(id, myList);
```

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense.  My code compiles with those couple adjustments.  Thanks!